# Wordpress search returns all pages regardless of search term

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have created a custom search page showing results only from children of two pages in the site. Problem is that no matter what the search term is, it returns all pages under those two. For any search term, it returns the same 200 pages

```
$s=get_search_query();
$args = array(
            's' =>$s
        );

if(isset($_GET['book'])) {
    $b = $_GET['book'];
    $args = array(
        'post_type'       => 'page',
        'posts_per_page'  => -1,
        'post_parent__in' => array(7253, 9859),
        'sentence'        => true,
        'exact'           => true,
        'order'           => 'ASC',
        'orderby'         => 'relevance',
    );
    $parent = new WP_Query( $args );
    if ( $parent->have_posts() ) : ?>
```

the `if(isset($_GET['book'])) {` check if search should go only through these two pages.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are overriding the args array.

Use the following code:

```
$s=get_search_query();


if(isset($_GET['book'])) {
    $b = $_GET['book'];
    $args = array(
        'post_type'       => 'page',
        'posts_per_page'  => -1,
        'post_parent__in' => array(7253, 9859),
        'sentence'        => true,
        'exact'           => true,
        'order'           => 'ASC',
        'orderby'         => 'relevance',
        's'               => $s
    );
    $parent = new WP_Query( $args );
    if ( $parent->have_posts() ) : ?>
```

Comment: If I do that, I get: `WordPress database error: [You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DESC, wp_posts.post_date ASC' at line 3]`